Is there a way to get a static graph output from litstudy?
I have code that creates a network out of a .csv file of academic paper properties that has been downloaded from the online database presented by Scopus.
The code utilises the litstudy module. This allows you to load the .csv file as a doc object (defined by the litstudy module. You can then create networks from the data, i.e. a network of authors that have published together, a network of papers that have cited each other. It also gives you the ability to plot this network graph. When looking at the code base for this module I can see that the plotting function is based on the pyvis module.
The main issue that I am having with the litstudy module is that it produces graphs that are have a good layout, however, these graphs will move, making it difficult to analyse the results. I have read online that if you change the interactive property of the litstudy.network.plot_network() to False it will produce a static graph. However, when I do this, the nodes plot directly ontop of each other. Is there a way to preserve the layout of this graph but stop it moving. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached a snapshot of the graph when the interactive property is set to True(https://i.sstatic.net/F0pDnKRV.png) and when the property is set to False (https://i.sstatic.net/etHjeBvI.png).
The code is as follows:
soc_path = (
r'C:/Documents/Post_Doc/Writing_and_Learning/Lit_Review/Web_of_Science_Seagrass_Organic_Carbon.csv'
)

hab_path = (
r'C:/Documents/Post_Doc/Writing_and_Learning/Lit_Review/Web_of_Science_Seagrass_Habitat_Mapping.csv'
)

def scopus_doc_generator(path):# , year
    
    docs = litstudy.load_scopus_csv(path.replace('.csv', '_amended.csv'))
    
    #docs_refined = docs.filter_docs(lambda d: d.publication_year >= year)

    docs_found, docs_not_found = litstudy.refine_crossref(docs) 
    
    return docs_found

soc_docs_found = scopus_doc_generator(soc_path) #, 2000

hab_map_docs_found = scopus_doc_generator(hab_path) #, 2000

total_docs_found = soc_docs_found | hab_map_docs_found

coauthor_network = litstudy.build_coauthor_network(total_docs_found)

litstudy.network.plot_network(
    coauthor_network, max_node_size = 75, interactive = False
)

I tried the following python code:
soc_path = (
r'C:/Documents/Post_Doc/Writing_and_Learning/Lit_Review/Web_of_Science_Seagrass_Organic_Carbon.csv'
)

hab_path = (
r'C:/Documents/Post_Doc/Writing_and_Learning/Lit_Review/Web_of_Science_Seagrass_Habitat_Mapping.csv'
)

def scopus_doc_generator(path):# , year
    
    docs = litstudy.load_scopus_csv(path.replace('.csv', '_amended.csv'))
    
    #docs_refined = docs.filter_docs(lambda d: d.publication_year >= year)

    docs_found, docs_not_found = litstudy.refine_crossref(docs) 
    
    return docs_found

soc_docs_found = scopus_doc_generator(soc_path) #, 2000

hab_map_docs_found = scopus_doc_generator(hab_path) #, 2000

total_docs_found = soc_docs_found | hab_map_docs_found

coauthor_network = litstudy.build_coauthor_network(total_docs_found)

litstudy.network.plot_network(
    coauthor_network, max_node_size = 75, interactive = False
)

I expected a static graph output with nodes that are not over lapping each other.
Edit:
I have the data for both noteboooks stored at the following repositories:
soc_csv
hab_csv
Solution:
I found a solution for the problem on a GitHub conversation about stopping the physics from a pyvis graph after it reached stabilisation. This was alluded to by @furas's when they suggested it might be a Javascript problem.
If you add line outlined by the GitHub to the template.html file in the template folder of the pyvis site package you can then add the following two lines to the plot_network function of the network.py file of the litstudy package and then you get a stable output:
template_dir = 'wherever you have saved the new template.html file'
v.set_template_dir(template_dir)

return v.show(file_name)


it seems it uses pyvis.network.network which has toggle_physics but I don't know it can be executed on litstudy. Maybe if you would create minimal working code with example data in code so we could simply copy and run it, and then maybe we could test it. - see: python - pyvis: is there a way to disable physics without losing graph's layout? - Stack Overflow

I have added the data to DropBox. The code should run as is. I have tried toggling the physics on the settings but that losses the layout provided by the module. I would like the layout but just to not have the graph move. I have tried pyplot but that does not seem to set up nodes that have connections adjacent to each other.

I think it calculates position using JavaScript in browser - so it may need to add some JavaScript to stop interaction/physics. And it may need more work

@furas I got it fixed by following a solution on a GitHub repository based on your suggestion.

You could add it as answer - it will be more visible for other people, Stackoverflow Search, Google Search. You could add link to GitHub with code, but also you could add code directly in answer. And you can accept your answer, and later you can upvote your answer :)

Solution:
I found a solution for the problem on a GitHub conversation about stopping the physics from a pyvis graph after it reached stabilisation. This was alluded to by @furas when they suggested it might be a Javascript problem. The initial fix was outlined on GitHub.
If you copy the template.html from the template folder of the pyvis site package to another place in your computer you can then add the following line:


network.once("stabilizationIterationsDone", function() { document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '100%'; document.getElementById('bar').style.width = '496px'; document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 0; // really clean the dom element
setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.display = 'none';}, 500); // add this line network.setOptions( { physics: false } ); }); // start block addition {% else %} network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone", function() { network.setOptions(
{ physics: false } ); }); //end block addition {% endif %}



You can then add the following two lines to the plot_network function of the network.py file of the litstudy package and then you get a stable output:
template_dir = 'C:/Users/gerar/Documents/Templates/template.html'
v.set_template_dir(template_dir)

return v.show(file_name)

